# Why saves donwload-manager file to storage/emulated/0 directory in external storage?

Tags: android, file, path, storage, android-download-manager

I've read much about saving files, android directory structure, permissions, paths etc. but cant fix my problem.

**What i have already**

I requested WRITE and READ storage permissions and can create a folder in external storage.

**What i want to do**

I want to save files with download manager to this folder, i created.
The folder is in external storage (named "internal storage" in my android file explorer app) in the same directory such as "WhatsApp" or "Downloads"("/storage/emulated/0/sMyFolder" or "Internal storage/sMyFolder")

[image: File structure]

I've already tried to do so, but if i try to set setDestinationInExternalPublicDir() for download-managers request,  the file will stored to the "storage" folder you can see in the screenshot (Internal storage/storage/emulated/0/sMyFolder/MyFile) and i dont know why it isnt stored in main directory in my "sMyFolder", you can also see in the picture.

Here my code:

```
    Folder f;
    private static void makeFolder(){
        f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sMyFolder");
        if (!f.exists()) f.mkdirs();
    }

     public void download(){
          // other code
          makeFolder();
          request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(f.getPath(), "MyFile1.txt");
     }
```

Where is the problem with my code? Could someone help me please...

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: The `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` method does not work as you expect. The first argument you pass is meant to be an external directory type, not a full path; e.g., `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`. To save to an arbitrary external folder, I believe you'll have to use the `setDestinationUri()` method instead; e.g., `setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(f, "MyFile1.txt")));`.

Comment: Thanks that works!!! I would like to mark your explanation as "solved my provblem"(green check), if you would write an answer!!!